# Django DRF how to overwrite Custom throttles

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement this [Custom throttles](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#custom-throttles). I want to disallow every request if it exceeded a certain number of seconds. For example, If anyone sends more than 10 requests per seconds then I want to stop and wait 20seconds before sending  new request. I tried this code but didn't work

```
class CstomRateThrottle(throttling.BaseThrottle):
    def allow_request(self, request, view, wait=20):
        return True
```

They saying Optionally I may also override the .wait() method but don't know how.

I also tried this but didn't work

```
class CstomRateThrottle(throttling.AnonRateThrottle):
    def parse_rate(self, rate=(10, 20)): #10 request in very 20 seconds 

        if rate is None:
            return (None, None)
        num, period = rate.split('/')
        num_requests = int(num)
        duration = timeparse(period)
        return (num_requests, duration)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to customize the `wait` function like the following.

```
class CstomRateThrottle(throttling.BaseThrottle):
    def wait(self):
        return 10
```

Comment: thanks but how to add logic. Your current code restricting user directly but I want to only restrict when request will be  >10 and he need to be wait 10 seconds